# Tamagawa numbers of elliptic curve after quadratic twist

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

The Tamagawa numbers for an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ are given by $n_{p}(E) := [E(\mathbb{Q}_{p}):E^{0}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})]$, where $E^{0}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ is the group of points having good reduction. Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant of a given $E$. Let $E\otimes \chi_{D}$ be a quadratic twist of $E$ with discriminant $\Delta_{D}$.

**Question**: Is it true that for primes $p \nmid D$ we have $n_{p}(E\otimes\chi_{D}) = n_{p}(E)$?

Page 4 of [this paper](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Efranz/publ/conics.pdf) gives some insight on computing $n_{p}$. I know that $\Delta_{D} = \Delta D^{6}$ (I think?), and so if $p \nmid D$ then...? Perhaps knowing what happens to reduction types after twisting $E$ could help.

[this overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236283/tamagawa-numbers-of-elliptic-curves-and-quadratic-base-change) could shed some light as well.

Comment: No. E.g. [this curve](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/135/a/1) and [its -7 twist](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/6615/a/1) at 3.

Comment: Also, in any case, $p\nmid D$ is definitely not enough. For example, if $D\not\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then $\chi_D$ will be ramified at $2$.